# Could not load type 'System.WEb.Ui.WebResourceAttribute' while executing 'migration'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I tried to execute `add-migration` but when I build it, I get this error. I am using `ASP.NET CORE 3.1`. I could not find any solutions from googling.

**Error**

```
add-migration addedFirstLastNamestoUsers
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](Assembly element)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureReferencedServices(IServiceCollection services, String provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build(DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

Comment: I'm having this exact same error using Unity's entity component system. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute` dll is applied in `.NET Framework 2.0-4.8 version`, it is not supported in .net core.

It is recommended that you delete this reference in your current project.

More detail, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webresourceattribute?view=netframework-4.8).